# How to suppress output of systemctl?

Tags: shell, systemd, io-redirection

How to suppress output of systemctl?

I have tried

```
systemctl --quiet
```

```
systemctl -q
```

and even

```
systemctl 2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

none of these seem to work when testing for service is disabled when said service is already disabled?

```
systemctl -q is-disabled dhcpcd
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect both stderr and stdout to /dev/null with /bin/sh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80629/redirect-both-stderr-and-stdout-to-dev-null-with-bin-sh)

Comment: I'm looking for the opposite: how do you make "reload" give any feedback?  *Why* is there no "--verbose" when it has "--quiet".  Still not liking it.

Answer (score 8):

`systemctl` does not support `is-disabled` option, you probably
meant `is-enabled`.  To use it and redirect both stdout and
stderr to /dev/null:

```
systemctl is-enabled dhcpcd >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

`is-disabled` is not a `systemctl` keyword.

This is closer to what I think you want:

```
systemctl status service &>/dev/null || echo "is-disabled"
```

I'm using the shell OR branching operator. That line will print `is-disabled` if the previous command return an error status which systemctl will do in case the service is disabled. If you want to test if the service is enabled instead you can use `&&` instead of `||`. The `echo` is just an example of a following command.

Comment: Weird, the error I was seeing is now nonexistent.... disabling something twice would through a message to stderr that seemed undirect-able.

Comment: @AdminBee 'verb' is the term used by systemd.

Comment: Nothing is carved in stone; you can always (and should :) ) edit your own post to add corrections as you see fit.

Comment: Regarding the current version `systemctl status $SERVICE &>/dev/null || echo "is-disabled"`: echoing "is-disabled" is misleading, as `systemctl` has various nonzero exit statuses, each indicating something specific. And a unit/`$SERVICE` can be *enabled* while `systemctl status $SERVICE` returns a nonzero exit status , See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html